# Apache sentry hive grant insert privileges but it did not work

Tags: hive, apache-sentry

**insert into limifang_oracle_store002(id,name) values(1,'lisi');**

exception：
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.InvalidTableException: Table not found limifang_oracle_store002 (state=42000,code=40000)
0: jdbc:hive2://192.168.2.16:2181,192.168.2.1> insert into liminfang_oracle_store002(id,name) values(1,'lisi');
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. Permission denied: user=kaif1, access=EXECUTE, inode="/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/kaif1/.staging":**root:supergroup:drwx------**

Permission information is as follows:
**show grant role  kaif1;**

|database| table | partition  | column  | principal_name  | principal_type  | privilege  | grant_option  |   grant_time   | grantor  |

| ziy_db_109  | **liminfang_oracle_store002**  |      kaif1           | ROLE            | **DELETE**   | false         | 1022296989000
| ziy_db_109   |**liminfang_oracle_store002**  |     kaif1    | ROLE            | **INSERT**     | false         | 1022295356000  |

Answer (score 1):

Check the Hadoop cluster HDFS in those groups, if there are **hadoop, hdfs, supergroup** and other groups.

1. first establish the corresponding user test and supergroup groups (Hadoop or HDFS group) in the Linux system.

2 add test users to the supergroup group (or Hadoop, HDFS group).

3 Connect hive with hive user (administrator) beeline, create role: test_role, execute command: create role test_role;

4 grant permission to test_role and execute the command: grant all on testdb. testtable to role test_role; (there must be a library testdb, table testtable in his)

5 assign the test_role role to the test user to execute the command :grant test_role to group test;

6. verify that use test user beeline to connect hive:  use testdb; show tables; check if it is wrong.